# How to get data from a weather RSS feed using javascript and ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'weatherProxy.php',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (xml){
        titles=this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('title')
        for(i=0; j <titles.length; i++){
            out+= titles[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '<br>'                    
        }
    }
});
```

weatherProxy.php

```
if (isset($_GET['http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2645425/3dayforecast.rss'])){
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo file_get_contents($_GET['http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2645425/3dayforecast.rss']);
```

I am trying to take the information from the url through an ajax get request, I pass the rss feed through a proxy to prevent the "No access control allow origin" error. At the moment it doesn't work was wondering if I'm doing something wrong. I need it to add each title on the RSS feed to the array titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$_GET` ... you are using it incorrectly

Try:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo file_get_contents('http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2645425/3dayforecast.rss');
```

Then in ajax success you can simplfy the parsing using jQuery methods

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function(){
   var title = $(this).find('title').text();
   console.log(title)
})
```

Comment: Still getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined

Comment: I mistakenly had quotes around the `xml` variable...try again with update

Comment: Works, perfect! Thank you!